# Which interface can replace IArcPadExtension?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, arcobjects, arcpad

I trying to migrate a code written for arcgis desktop and I have there a IArcPadExtension, but here (http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/type_changes_between_9_3_and_10/000100000408000000/) we can read that this Interface removed. Can someone tell me which interface can be used instead of IArcPadExtension?

Answer (score 1):

We can replace that with IArcPadExchange located in ArcPadToolsGen2.dll, which is delivered with arcpad 10